# sh script doesn't run from crontab

Tags: shell, cron, sh, cron-task

I have a sh script that works fine if run it from terminal `node /users/<my username>/Documents/work/cron-test/run-node.sh`

```
#!usr/bin/env node
node /users/<my username>/Documents/work/cron-test/server.js
```

I setup crontab like this:

```
* * * * * sh /users/<my username>/documents/work/cron-test/run-node.sh >> /users/<my username>/documents/cron.log 2&>1
```

It shows no errors, but script doesn't execute

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tagentially, the shebang is wrong. A shell script should have `#!/bin/sh` on its first line (though if you are running it with `sh` explicitly anyway, that line is just a useless comment).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to specify exact path for node in sh script.

```
/Users/<my username>/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node /Users/<my username>/documents/work/cron-test/server.js
```

And for MacOS it is important to give access to system for cron.

[image]

To find cron exec you can check this directory `/usr/sbin/cron` and drag it to `Full Disk Access`

[image]